# Power shell script combining results together. Don’t want it to happen

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that I want to output to the console the info from get-localgroupmember (for admins) and then (separately) the info for get-localgroupmember (for Users) after that. But when I run the two, the results get combined and the output doesn’t display for the first call and then responds to the second/last call with all the results in the same objectclass list.

How do I get it to execute one at a time separately?

```
$userName = "Student"

Write-Host "`nShowing local user`n"
Get-LocalUser -Name $userName;


Write-Host "`nShowing Users group`n";
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users";

Write-Host "`nShowing Administrators group`n";
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators";

Write-Host "`nShowing local users`n"
Get-LocalUser -Name $userName;
```

I tried to assign each to their own variables and then using write-host to output each of the variables but it still did the same thing.

This is what I tried, got the same output

```
Write-Host "`nShowing Users group`n";
$object = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users";
Write-Output $object

Write-Host "`nShowing Administrators group`n";
$object = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators";
Write-Output  $object
```

if I run it all together I get this:

```
Showing local user



Showing Users group


Showing Administrators group

Name    Enabled Description
----    ------- -----------
Student True

Name            : MSI\user
SID             : S-1-5-21-1457208496-2238809947-3401341024-1001
PrincipalSource : MicrosoftAccount
ObjectClass     : User


Name            : MSI\student
SID             : S-1-5-21-1457208496-2238809947-3401341024-1004
PrincipalSource : Local
ObjectClass     : User


Name            : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
SID             : S-1-5-11
PrincipalSource : Unknown
ObjectClass     : Group


Name            : NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
SID             : S-1-5-4
PrincipalSource : Unknown
ObjectClass     : Group


Name            : MSI\Administrator
SID             : S-1-5-21-1457208496-2238809947-3401341024-500
PrincipalSource : Local
ObjectClass     : User


Name            : MSI\user
SID             : S-1-5-21-1457208496-2238809947-3401341024-1001
PrincipalSource : MicrosoftAccount
ObjectClass     : User
```

If I remove the Get-LocalUser -Name $userName; call, I get this:

```
Showing Users group



Showing Administrators group

ObjectClass Name                             PrincipalSource
----------- ----                             ---------------
User        MSI\user                         MicrosoftAccount
User        MSI\student                      Local
Group       NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Unknown
Group       NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE         Unknown
User        MSI\Administrator                Local
User        MSI\user                         MicrosoftAccount
```

I want two separate objectclass lists with space in between. As if I typed each one in separately by hand, hitting enter after each command.
See what I am trying to accomplish here:

```
Showing Users group

ObjectClass Name                             PrincipalSource
----------- ----                             ---------------
User        MSI\user                         MicrosoftAccount
User        MSI\Student                      Local
Group       NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Unknown
Group       NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE         Unknown

Showing Administrators group

ObjectClass Name              PrincipalSource
----------- ----              ---------------
User        MSI\Administrator Local
User        MSI\user          MicrosoftAccount

Showing local users

Name    Enabled Description
----    ------- -----------
student True
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Just convert all of the Powershell objects to strings by appending `| Out-String`:

```
$userName = "Student"

Write-Host "`nShowing local user`n"
Get-LocalUser -Name $userName | Out-String;

Write-Host "`nShowing Users group`n";
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users" | Out-String;

Write-Host "`nShowing Administrators group`n";
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" | Out-String;

Write-Host "`nShowing local users`n"
Get-LocalUser -Name $userName | Out-String;
```

Doing so will give you your desired output.